# Descending ordering doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure doesn't perform descending order of data I don't know why !

```
BEGIN 
    SET nocount ON; 

    WITH ordereddata 
         AS (SELECT *, 
                    rn = Row_number() 
                           OVER ( 
                             ORDER BY articleid ) 
             FROM   articles) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   ordereddata 
    WHERE  rn <= @UpperBound 
           AND rn >= @LowerBound 
    ORDER  BY articleid DESC 
END
```

this is the result when I give the @Upperbound and @LowerBound values

> aricleid 54 55 56  57 . . .

Comment: articleid is the primary key

Comment: as I don't see syntax or logic error , so try to restart your server and retrype your stored procedure !

Comment: yes I will try this , as @Vignesh Kumar said it works fine with him !!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH OrderedData
as (
  select * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articleid desc )  FROM articles
   )

select * from OrderedData
where rn <= @UpperBound AND rn >= @LowerBound 
ORDER BY articleid desc
END
```

Comment: well I did 3 descendings , so it is an odd number ,so I did undo for the undo ! , like making just one desc !

Comment: Row Number will not be considered here

Comment: alright , I removed the 2 extra desc , and still the same result !

Comment: @AyaMohammad let me check, but i tried with your code ,it's working fine

Comment: really ! and the result is descending

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH OrderedData
as (
  select * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articleid)  FROM articles 
  )

select * from OrderedData
where rn <= @UpperBound AND rn >= @LowerBound 
ORDER BY articleid desc
END
```

Comment: that was what I did from the beginning actually , and when It didn't work I edited it to be as I asked it :/